# Can I tell MSBuild to look for a project's dependencies in a non-standard folder?

Tags: msbuild, build-process

Our build script effectively does this:

```
1) build project_a.csproj into non/standard/output/path
1) build project_b.csproj into non/standard/output/path
2) build tests_for_project_a.csproj into non/standard/test_output/path
```

Building the test project causes any referenced projects to be built a second time, since the output path isn't the same as what's in project_a.csproj. Is there a way to tell MSBuild where to go looking for those binaries?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best option I have found is to run the following:

```
1a) msbuild project_a.csproj
1b) msbuild project_a.csproj into non/standard/output/path
```

When I do step `1b`, it doesn't rebuild the binaries, only copies them to the final destination.